# Invalid Syntax Error at the end of a concatenated list

Tags: python, syntax-error, sage

I have concatenated a list together and then while trying to load it into SAGE using %attach (filename) , I keep getting an error:

```
File "/projects/f6f895ae-ee58-4e39-9ebc-34b6285d9dec/regs_180k_200k_conca.py", line 5484
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
```

This line is AFTER my last line in my list. So in this case, there is no line 5484 in my .py document. Why is this the case?

These are the last two lines in my list. They have all been concatenated appropriately with +\ .

```
[[['199988f1', 1], 160, 161, [[241, 2]]], [['199990a1', 2], 158, 160, [[523, 0], [613, 0]]], [['199990b1', 2], 156, 161, [[13, 1], [283, 0], [557, 3], [673, 0], [827, 0]]], [['199990d1', 1], 156, 158, [[43, 2], [163, 2]]], [['199990e1', 1], 154, 158, [[11, -1], [13, 2], [19, -1], [787, 2]]], [['199990f1', 1], 160, 161, [[317, 2]]], [['199991a1', 1], 152, 157, [[19, -1], [29, -1], [47, -1], [149, -1], [251, -1]]], [['199992a1', 2], 158, 160, [[5, 1], [479, 0]]], [['199992b1', 2], 151, 158, [[5, 1], [59, 0], [71, 3], [89, 0], [97, 0], [127, 3], [491, 0]]], [['199992c1', 2], 153, 157, [[7, 1], [79, 0], [409, 0], [719, 0]]]]+\
[[['199992d1', 1], 155, 155, []], [['199992e1', 1], 159, 159, []], [['199992f1', 1], 157, 160, [[5, 0], [29, 0], [79, -1]]], [['199992g1', 1], 162, 162, []], [['199993a1', 1], 158, 161, [[5, 2], [13, -1], [53, -1]]], [['199994b1', 1], 155, 159, [[7, 2], [11, 0], [283, -1], [449, -1]]], [['199994f1', 1], 158, 161, [[433, -1], [691, -1], [863, -1]]], [['199996a1', 1], 150, 160, [[7, 3], [13, -1], [37, -1], [97, -1], [103, -1], [257, -1], [331, 2], [383, -1], [541, -1], [811, -1]]], [['199998b1', 1], 156, 161, [[5, -1], [17, -1], [73, 2], [211, -1], [227, -1]]], [['199998e1', 1], 158, 161, [[5, -1], [239, -1], [283, -1]]], [['199998g1', 1], 152, 153, [[17, 2]]], [['199998h1', 1], 157, 158, [[283, -1]]], [['199998j1', 2], 153, 156, [[7, 3], [13, 3], [181, 0]]], [['199998k1', 2], 156, 160, [[23, 3], [79, 3], [167, 0], [461, 0]]], [['199998l1', 1], 156, 161, [[5, 2], [13, 2], [71, 2], [211, -1], [233, -1]]]]
```

This is the code that I used to generate my list.

```
D = CremonaDatabase()
regall=[]
bigtam = []
i = 0
for x in D.iter(range(190833,200000)):  ##change this range as necessary
    r = x.rank()
    if r > 0:
        if x.cremona_label()[-1] == '1':
            ptn = prod(x.tamagawa_numbers())
            if ptn > 1500:  ##choose your tamagawa product cutoff...i chose 1500
                print '%s, %s: large tamagawa product!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'%(x.cremona_label(), ptn)
                bigtam.append(x.cremona_label())
            else:
                A = [[x.cremona_label(), r]]
                B = []
                gocountall = 0
                gocountvr = 0
                for p in prime_range(5,1000):
                    if x.is_good(p) and x.is_ordinary(p):
                        reg = x.padic_regulator(p,prec=8)  ##try prec = 8 for all conductors between 80k and 200k
                        v = reg.valuation()
                        if v == r:
                            gocountvr = gocountvr + 1
                        if v != r:
                            B = B +  [[p, v]]
                        gocountall = gocountall+1
                 t2 = cputime()
                 regall = regall + [A + [gocountvr] + [gocountall] + [B]]
                 if i%10 == 9:
                      print regall[i-9:i+1]
                      sys.stdout.flush()
                 i = i+1

 print 'regs = ', regall
 sys.stdout.flush()
 print 'TO DO =', bigtam
 sys.stdout.flush()
```

Obviously I've removed all the 'large tamagawa product' printouts as well as concatenated the list nicely. I don't think the error is within the list itself because I have had that situation a couple of times and it specifies where the error is. So I've removed all cases of the list possibly not being correct.

I've also switched around the last line with other lines in my list and I get the same error each time. So I don't think it is a problem with the last line in particular because otherwise I think the error will move too.

I've also done this for other ranges and they have worked successfully.

Comment: show the last line and your traceback

Comment: You could be missing a parenthesis, Edit: he hadn't posted his last two lines yet

Comment: @Imirak, where do you see parens?

Comment: Is the parenthesis necessarily in the last one? I've tried switching my lines around and the error still remains the same. So it can't be a case of a parenthesis in a particular line, can it?

Comment: And there's also no traceback. That's the only two lines that the error gives.

Comment: post the actual code you are using in the last coupleof lines

Comment: WWhy is this being downvoted? If it is some trivial error that everybody knows how to change, then somebody should tell me how to do it. At the moment, I don't think that's the case?

Comment: This question is very, very hard to answer given the information you've provided.  Fortunately, since I'm the admin of the computer you're using, I can dig deeper :-)  Here's a gist showing that this is literally just a Python syntax error, so has nothing in particular to do with sage: https://gist.github.com/williamstein/49fc9a2857c89f099f69

Comment: If you add a single ] at the end of your file it imports fine. That said -- personally, I recommend you learn some new tools for reading in data for computations, instead of creating big .py files.   Some suggestions: (1) write a list of requested computations to a file and learn how to use open(...).xreadlines() to iterate through the lines of a file; or (2) use pickle (save/load functions in sage), or (3) use a sqlite database.  Constructing massive Python files to specify input isn't super robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case my comment isn't seen since it is so low on the list above: "If you add a single ] at the end of your file it imports fine."